# How to make a program like mouse locator with python? (like Free Utility to Locate Mouse Cursor Position)

Tags: python

How to make a program like mouse locator with python? (like Free Utility to Locate Mouse Cursor Position)
I don't know how to display the coordinates in the window when the mouse moves

```
import tkinter as tk
import pyautogui as pag

win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry('200x50+550+250')
win.title('Mos Loc')
win.config(bg='#323232')
win.attributes('-topmos',1)

lab = tk.Label(text ='')
lab.pack()

def pos():
   x = pag.position()
   lab.config(text = x)
```

Comment: Use pygame module : x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to update the text every *x* milliseconds to get an up-to-date coordinate of your cursor. The follow code does this using the `frame.mainloop()` function to keep the window alive, and the `frame.after(MILLISECONDS, FUNCITON)` to update the text.

```
import tkinter as tk
import pyautogui as pag

win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry('200x50+550+250')
win.title('Mos Loc')
win.config(bg='#323232')
win.attributes('-topmos', 1)

frame = tk.Frame()


lab = tk.Label(text='')
lab.pack()


def update():
    lab.configure(text=pag.position())
    frame.after(20, update)


update()
frame.mainloop()
```